# JPA - How do I map to a quick-lookup table?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, data-modeling

I have a contact entity that has >1 phone number `contact[contact, name, cell,work,home...]` and want to create a lookup table `phone_number[uid,contactuid,telephonenumber]` so that I can search through this table by telephone number to  find the contact.

With JPA - how would I configure to;

- Map the `phone_number` entity so that the entity will populated from the contact entity
- remove the `phone_number` record when the contacts number remove (or the contact is removed, remove all records)
- change `phone_number` record when the contacts number changes?

I was hoping to do all this in the DAO as this isn't really domain logic..

**Update - is the `contact->phone_number` relationship sensible to define in JPA or just map it using SQL in the DAO?

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you already have a Contact entity with several phone number fields:

- cellPhone
- workPhone
- homePhone

And you would like to find a contact given a phone number. If so, you don't need any additional table to do that:

```
select c from Contact c 
where c.cellPhone = :phoneNumber 
   or c.workPhone = :phoneNumber 
   or c.homePhone = :phoneNumber
```

But maybe you should have a Phone entity with a `phoneNumber` and a `type` (work, cell, etc.) fields, and have a bidirectional OneToMany association between Contact and Phone. Your query would then be

```
select c from Phone p
inner join p.contact c
where p.phoneNumber = :phoneNumber
```

which would certainly be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks JB - Yes that is what i am looking but the schema isn't the issue - is is the JPA relationships (and the invocations that take place when the contact telephone values are updated)..

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Please edit your question and show what you would like to do or what you have a problem with with Java code.

Comment: No Java code yet exists for the relationship (does for the contact but that is a standard contact entity) - working more conceptually to see how (or if) this type of relationship could be mapping and if so - is is sensible to do so in JPA (updated the question to reflect that)...

Comment: Doesn't my answer explain it? You could have a bidirectional OneToMany association between Contact and Phone. SQL is only necessary in unusual, extreme cases when uding JPA. JPQL is sufficient in 99% of the cases.